# C#.net Windows Application - Input data check before insert to Database

Tags: c#, .net, validation, ms-access-2007

I am making a booking system.

I can't figure out the validation algorithm for a series of data before it insert to DB.
The primary key will be the booking ID which is automatic generate by the system.

I need to validate the bdate, btime and sname. (bdate=booking time, btime=booking time, and sname=staff name)

In case of the bdate, btime and sname is same as what the client input. the system will alert its duplicate as the staff already have booking on the same date and time.

Please find my insert query at below and appreciated you can point me to the right way.

```
 private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //query for duplicate
        cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from Booking where sname = @newName and bdate = @newDate and btime = @newTime";
       // cmd.Parameters.Add("@newName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_cname.Text;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@newDate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = dtp_bdate.Value.Date;
       // cmd.Parameters.Add("@newTime", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dtp_btime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt");

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Booking(cname, bdate, btime, ccontact, sname) Values('" + txt_cname.Text + "','" + dtp_bdate.Value.Date + "','" + dtp_btime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt") + "','" + txt_ccontact.Text + "','" + txt_sname.Text + "')";
        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();

        int recordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        myCon.Close();

        if (recordCount>0)

        {
            // handle duplicates
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicated", "My Application",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }

       // cmd.Connection = myCon;
        //myCon.Open();
       //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //myCon.Close();
        //MessageBox.Show(dtp_bdate.Value.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show("Booking completed", "My Application",
       // MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have access to the database? A UNIQUE constraint would be much simpler to employ on those three fields. Unless booking the same customer twice on the same day/time is valid.

Comment: use sql paramaters to avoid sql injections, you can use stored procedures and check if data exists and throw sql exception else insert data

Comment: By the way, you've left yourself open not only to serious injection attacks, but also silly little mistakes. If the customer's name is Bill O'Reilly, your query will fail.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your datasource is Access? Otherwise, why are you using OleDb?

Comment: Rather than wait for the sql to fail due to unique index, why not try a select first? This will also allow you to modify the booking, if necessary.

Comment: Have you considered using EntityFramework or LinqToSQL as a ORM for your solution? Using one of these will significantly simplify your data validation tasks, and data access for that matter.

Comment: If select count is available then only do the insert if the existing count on those fields is zero. if count = do insert. And as others pointed out. Always use parameters and not inline build string query.

Comment: You can use `try`/`catch` in SQL to handle the `INSERT`.  That keeps the check and insert as one atomic operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private bool RecordExists(string name, DateTime date, string time)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //query for duplicate
        cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from Booking where sname = @newName and bdate = @newDate and btime = @newTime";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@newName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_cname.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@newDate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = dtp_bdate.Value.Date;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@newTime", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dtp_btime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt");

        myCon.Open();

        int recordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        myCon.Close();

        return recordCount > 0;
    }

    private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RecordExists(txt_cname.Text, dtp_bdate.Value.Date, dtp_btime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicated", "My Application", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            return;
        }

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Booking(cname, bdate, btime, ccontact, sname) Values(@newName, @newDate, @newTime, @newContact, @newSName)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@newName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_cname.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@newDate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = dtp_bdate.Value.Date;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@newTime", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dtp_btime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@newContact", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_ccontact.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@newSName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_sname.Text;

        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCon.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(dtp_bdate.Value.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("Booking completed", "My Application", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @paul ,

Thanks for your help again.

Firstly, the private bool class you have missed to establish a connection to DB. I have added cmd.Connection = myCon; and it works.

However, the prevention of duplicate still doesn't work correctly.
I try to input the same time, same date, and same staff name. The system will allow it to save even it already has the same record in DB.

Appreciated you can please help me further.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to check if the booking exists before performing your insert, so you need to add an additional step:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from booking where cname = @newName and bdate = @newDate and ctime = @newTime";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@newName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_cname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@newDate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = dtp_bdate.Value.Date;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@newTime", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dtp_btime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt");

cmd.Connection = myCon;
myCon.Open();

int recordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

myCon.Close();

if (recordCount>0)
{
    // handle duplicates
}
```

when you execute this, it will either return the number of matching rows, if this is 1 or more, then you should then invoke your duplicate logic.

edited to correct code

Comment: That is error while I replaced all your codes.
Below is the error return. Is that something to do with the MS Access I using as the DB instead of SQL?

'Error 1 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteScaler' and no extension method 'ExecuteScaler' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Project\Form1.cs 78 34 WindowsFormsApplication1
'

Comment: Sorry - typo - should be `ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: Sorry there is operator error:

'Error 1 Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int' D:\Project\Form1.cs 84 17 WindowsFormsApplication1
'

Comment: sorry, trying to do this from memory. perhaps `int recordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: Thanks. but I can't insert new record to DB...
Please see my coding at below answer as I can't post the coding in the comment box...

Comment: well, your insert code from your original question should work, although I would consider changing it to use parameters

Comment: Please see the revised coding. Now the DB accept everything. Even duplicated time, date, and the same sname.

Answer (score 0):

To check if there's existing field you can make a `Select` and then compare:

```
bool InfoRepeated()
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT cname FROM yourTable;");
        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        try
        {
            OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (txt_cname.Text.Equals((rdr[0].ToString())))
                {
                    myCon.Close();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            myCon.Close();
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            myCon.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Let me know if it works or the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

working useful code try this

```
BOMaster obj_data = new BOMaster();

obj_data.productid = tempid;
obj_data.categoryid =int.Parse(cmbcategory.SelectedValue.ToString());
obj_data.productcode = txtproductcode.Text;
obj_data.productname = txtproductname.Text;
obj_data.mqty = decimal.Parse(txtmqty.Text.ToString());

OleDbCommand mycmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from productmaster where productname=?", new OleDbConnection(Common.cnn));
BOMaster obj_datan = new BOMaster();

mycmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("productname", txtproductname.Text));
mycmd.Connection.Open();

OleDbDataReader myreader = mycmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

if (myreader.HasRows == true)
{
    // savestutus = "false";
    MessageBox.Show("Product Name Already Exist", "Product", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    txtproductname.Focus();
    return;
}
mycmd.Connection.Close();

ProductDAL obj_dal = new ProductDAL();

if (obj_dal.Save(obj_data))
{
    Clear();
}
```